# How do I create and use DateFormat with a given date in another annotation?

Tags: java, string, list, date, collections

Get the details of a Shipment with the expected date of delivery. Also get the number of shipment status available for that shipment, meaning the number of intermediate traversals. Write a program to compare if the expected date on the final status of the shipment and the actual expected date of the Shipment and display whether the Shipment has arrived 'on time' or 'before' or 'after' the expected date.

```
public class ShipmentMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the shipment details :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userDeatil = sc.next();
        String[] s = userDeatil.split(",");
        
        Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
        ShipmentStatus status = new ShipmentStatus();

        for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
            
            if (j == 0) {
            shipment.setid(s[j]);
            } else if (j == 1) {
            shipment.setsourcePort(s[j]);
            } else if (j == 2) {
            shipment.setdestinationPort(s[j]);
            } else if (j == 3) {
            shipment.setexpectedDeliveryDate(s[j]);
            } else if (j == 4) {
            shipment.setcustomerName(s[j]);
            } 
        
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Input and Output 1:**

```
Enter the shipment details :
STAJU01,Hong Kong,Cochin,20-05-2017,karthick
```

I am unable to input with the date field. Please guide me on how I can input this.

Comment: Why do you use a loop? It could be easier to read without it. Whats your exact problem in splitting the date?

Comment: What does *i am unable to input with the date field* exactly mean?

Comment: **Hint:** `scanner.next()` will only consider characters up to the next whitespace and you have *Hong Kong* in this input `String`. Make it `scanner.nextLine()` and try again...

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Date` and `DateFormat` classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes   Got a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`. To parse a specific format, use `DateTimeFormatter`. And, “detail” is misspelled in your code.

Comment: i used a loop because i have set the input values in Shipment class set method. then i have to get the date from shipment class and compare the dates in Shipment status  class.

Comment: public class Shipment {
private String id;
private String sourcePort; private String destinationPort; private Date expectedDeliveryDate;
private String customerName;
  private ShipmentStatus[] shipmentStatus;
     
     public String getid() {
   return id;
  }
  public void setid(String id) {
   this.id = id;
  }
  public String getsourcePort() {
   return sourcePort;
  }
  public void setsourcePort(String sourcePort) {
   this.sourcePort = sourcePort;
  }

Comment: public String gedestinationPortt() {
   return destinationPort;
  }
  public void setdestinationPort(String destinationPort) {
   this.destinationPort = destinationPort;
  }
  public Date getexpectedDeliveryDate(){
      return expectedDeliveryDate;
  }
  public void setexpectedDeliveryDate(Date expectedDeliveryDate){
      this.expectedDeliveryDate=expectedDeliveryDate;
  }
  public String getcustomerName() {
   return customerName;
  }
  public void setcustomerName(String customerName) {
   this.customerName = customerName;}

Comment: public Shipment(){
         
     }
     
     public Shipment(String id,String sourcePort,String destinationPort,Date expectedDeliveryDate, String customerName){
         
     }}

Comment: The above 3 comments is the shipment class where i have to set and get values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is meant to guide you to avoid the problems with your code and to help you solve the problem where you are stuck.

The first point is: Use `Scanner#nextLine` instead of `Scanner#next` as `Scanner#next` will stop scanning after it finds the first space i.e. it will scan only up to **STAJU01,Hong** for the input, **STAJU01,Hong Kong,Cochin,20-05-2017,karthick**

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the shipment details: ");

        // Use Scanner#nextLine to scan the full line
        String userDetail = sc.nextLine();

        String userDetailParts[] = userDetail.split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userDetailParts));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the shipment details: STAJU01,Hong Kong,Cochin,20-05-2017,karthick
[STAJU01, Hong Kong, Cochin, 20-05-2017, karthick]
```

Try running this code with the same input after changing `sc.nextLine()` to `sc.next()` and you will understand the difference.

After splitting the input into an array, you can access the elements using their indices e.g. by using `userDetailParts[3]`, you can access the date string. The `for` loop in your code is unnecessary.

The second point is: do not use the outdated date-time API e.g `java.util.Date` and `java.text.DateFormat`. Use the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) instead. Learn more about it from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Given date string
        String dateStr = "20-05-2017";

        // Define the pattern for formatting
        DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, inputFormatter);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Now, if you want to print the date in some other format, you can define the
        // format accordingly e.g.
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
        String formatted = outputFormatter.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-05-20
Saturday May 20, 2017
```

However, if you still insist to use the legacy API for date-time and its formatting, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        // Given date string
        String dateStr = "20-05-2017";

        // Define the pattern for formatting
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);

        // Print date using the default format (i.e. Date#toString)
        System.out.println(date);

        // Print date using your custom format
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sat May 20 00:00:00 BST 2017
20-05-2017
```

Comment: i used a loop to set values in shipping class

Comment: Once i enter the code.. in a single line with delimeter  without loop  how can i set the values

Comment: public class Shipment {
 
   private String id;
     private String sourcePort;
     private String destinationPort;
     private Date expectedDeliveryDate;
     private String customerName;
     private ShipmentStatus[] shipmentStatus;
     
     public String getid() {
   return id;
  }
  public void setid(String id) {
   this.id = id;
  }
  public String getsourcePort() {
   return sourcePort;
  }
  public void setsourcePort(String sourcePort) {
   this.sourcePort = sourcePort;
  }
  public String gedestinationPortt() {
   return destinationPort;
  }

Comment: public void setdestinationPort(String destinationPort) {
   this.destinationPort = destinationPort;
  }
  public Date getexpectedDeliveryDate(){
      return expectedDeliveryDate;
  }
  public void setexpectedDeliveryDate(Date expectedDeliveryDate){
      this.expectedDeliveryDate=expectedDeliveryDate;
  }
  public String getcustomerName() {
   return customerName;
  }
  public void setcustomerName(String customerName) {
   this.customerName = customerName;
   
  }
  

     public Shipment(){
         
     }

Comment: public Shipment(String id,String sourcePort,String destinationPort,Date expectedDeliveryDate, String customerName){
        this.id = id;
      this.sourcePort = sourcePort;
      this.destinationPort = destinationPort;
       this.expectedDeliveryDate=expectedDeliveryDate;
       this.customerName = customerName;
     }

Comment: the above 3 comments are the shipping class

Comment: Should i call the shipping constructor to set the values?? or should i individually set the values??

Comment: `shipment.setid(userDetailParts[0]);shipment.setsourcePort(userDetailParts[1]);shipment.setdestinationPort(userDetailParts[2]);shipment.setexpectedDeliveryDate(LocalDate.parse(userDetailParts[3], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));shipment.setcustomerName(userDetailParts[4]);`. Also change the type of `expectedDeliveryDate` to `LocalDate` (currently it is of type `Date` in your code).

Comment: Thanks. But my requirement insists that i use type DATE only. Can u change the code according to that for the date filed.

Comment: All right. I've updated my answer to include the option of using `Date` instead of `LocalDate`. You will have to do: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
shipment.setid(userDetailParts[0]);
shipment.setsourcePort(userDetailParts[1]);
shipment.setdestinationPort(userDetailParts[2]);
shipment.setexpectedDeliveryDate(sdf.parse(userDetailParts[3]));
shipment.setcustomerName(userDetailParts[4]);` Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 3):

You could cut the first two Characters off the String and save it, parse the Value into an int or something. Then you could cut the "-" character off and proceed with the next to int Chars. In the end you need to cut off four digits. After this you can easily add it to your Date and compare it to others. (For example Date.Format.SHORT)